# Run Google Sheets script on closing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to use a trigger in my Google Sheet, similar to `onOpen()`, but instead to trigger when I close the sheet. However, I haven't found anything like that built-in in the Google API guides, nor anything others have posted, and am not sure how to write one. Any help?

Comment: I don't think this is possible right now

Comment: @RobinGertenbach huh. Weird that onOpen() works, but no onClose()... do you think some sort of workaround is possible?

Answer (score 4):

At this time there is no onClose trigger. To learn about the available triggers see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/.

At this time Google Apps Script users can't create custom triggers, so a feature request should posted on Google Apps Script Issues. In this case someone else already did it. You could star it to let the Google Apps Script team that you are interested on it:

Issue [2334](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2334):    OnClose() or OnExit() would be amazing!

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that, that's the reason I'm asking... any idea about whether or not that would be easy to implement by oneself?

Comment: It was not clear for me which guides did you saw. Anyway, I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea about a custom implementation?

Comment: What do you mean by "custom implementation"?

Comment: Like a user-written script. Maybe one can check permanently if the document is open somewhere, once not -> it's just been closed. Something like that?